# Optimizing JS for IE8 - String.replace and String.match

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, internet-explorer-8

A website (unfortunately I cannot give the URL here) is freezing the browser (IE8) for several seconds on each page load. I opened the Developer tools, Profiler tab, and I saw the most time-consuming operations were String.match (executed 6000-8000 times, taking 22+ seconds), and String.replace (executed 60000-80000 times, taking 23+ seconds).

How can I get a clue on where these functions are being called - it sounds to me it is jQuery that matches selections, but I am not sure.

Comment: _"opened the Developer tools, Profiler tab, and I saw the most time-consuming operations were String.match (executed 6000-8000 times, taking 22+ seconds)"_ Does developer tab provide source and line of `.match()` , `.replace()` calls ?

Comment: No, no line mentioned, otherwise I would've been able to see that.

Comment: Tried viewing source of of `js` at page ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a clue on where these functions are being called

You can add a script, above all other scripts, that intercepts the calls:

```
var realReplace = String.prototype.replace;
String.prototype.replace = function() {
    // You can do something here if you like

    return realReplace.apply(this, arguments); // arguments is a predefined symbol (looks like pseudo-code, I know, but it isn't)
};
```

...and similarly for `String#match`.

This gives you a convenient place to set a breakpoint, for instance.

Naturally you'd remove this when done debugging, as it would only make the problem worse. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding "debugger;" where your comment line is ("Do something here"), but unfortunately now the debugger stops at the line of the new code addon, and I still cannot see where that happens in the original code.

Comment: @vladko13: I would have used a debugger breakpoint on the `return` line rather than `debugger`, but either way. Then look in the "call stack" to see what called it (and what called that, and what called *that*, etc.).